# Is there a way to keep a logbook in R functions?

Tags: r, function, error-handling

I'm working with functions in R which take a long time to complete. Sometimes an error occurs and I cannot see where it goes wrong... Is there a way to add a sort of logbook so I know up to where no error occurred? I tried writeLines() to a txt file, but it slows the function significantly...
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/loggit/index.html, by adding `message()` commands it creates a log where exactly the function fails. Additionally, there's `tryCatch` to include error handling in function execution.

Comment: How about the classic, `print("check point 1")`, `print("check point 2")`, etc. approach?

Comment: Thanks, these are both good ideas!